# Android Stuido : Out of memory (Java heap space) error for library after pc shut down

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

hi i about 7 hours working an this issue but i got the same error every time
every thing was fine i tried to run my app on virtual device but my laptop suddenly run out of battery
when i turned on my PC AndroidStudio showed me this error i can not rebuild project i tried so many different ways but its not working

i think this error is for Matrial Dialogs Library take look at image

1. I cleaned windows cache
2. I cleaned Gradle Cache
3. I deleted Gradle And download it again
4. I Added *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m*
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m this Two line to Gradle.Properties
5. I Edited The studio.exe.vmoptions file in Android Studio Location
6. I Added _JAVA_OPTION
7. I Tried to fix this from configure "Edit Custom VM Option" but i got the same error
8. After All i upgraded my AndroidStudio to version 4.0
   but i got the same error again

i really need your help

[AndroidStudio Error - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6SnW.png)

Answer (score 1):

try this , add it in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }
}
```

Comment: I added earlier Nour Eldien Mohamed

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271816/wired-out-of-memory-java-heap-space-error-with-ffmpeg-library ?

Comment: yes i tried this one (5) but its not working for me